Local Linear Fit
What do you call it when you have a set of known $(x,y)$ data points and you estimate a $y$-value for a given $x$-value by performing a linear fit between its two known neighbor $(x,y)$ points?
As an example known data is $(0,0), (1,1), (2,4)$ and you want to know the value of $y$ for $x=1.5$. So, based on the linear fit between $(1,1)$ and $(2,4)$ it's $1 + (1.5-1)*(4-1)/(2-1) = 2.5$.
I know there are much better estimation approaches, but this is a commonly used one and I can't think what it is properly called.

What you describe is interpolation. Since you use only two points it's linear interpolation. Note: French and English version of Wikipedia are quite detailed, while within the version in German it's just a marginal note of the vast subject "Interpolation (Mathematik)".
